# Need to create combinations of Parents/Children/Dogs, but can't get past 2nd level of CTE

Tags: sql-server-2005, join, cte

I've hit a brick wall and please ask help.

I'm building a table up for (in this example) a ticketing system
where e.g. Ticket 1 will allow
Parent: Either parent Peter or Sally,
Child: to come without a child or with a child (either Sam, Pete or John),
Dog: and either without a dog or with one of the dogs (DogMatix,Snowy,Bliksem)

The table layout is that the Parent/Child/Dog is a parameter, and I can get (with CTE) to the Parent/Child relationships to all show, but not the next level showing the dogs too

```
declare @Ticket table
(
TID int
)

declare @Param table
(PID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
TID int,
ParamType varchar(20),
Val  varchar(40)
)


Insert into @Ticket(TID) Select(1)
Insert into @Ticket(TID) Select(2)


Insert into @Param(TID,ParamType,Val) values(1,'Parent','ParentPeter')
Insert into @Param(TID,ParamType,Val) values(1,'Parent','ParentSally')
Insert into @Param(TID,ParamType,Val) values(1,'Child','ChildSam')
Insert into @Param(TID,ParamType,Val) values(1,'Child','ChildPete')
Insert into @Param(TID,ParamType,Val) values(1,'Child','ChildJohn')
Insert into @Param(TID,ParamType,Val) values(1,'Dog','DogDogMatix')
Insert into @Param(TID,ParamType,Val) values(1,'Dog','DogSnowy')
Insert into @Param(TID,ParamType,Val) values(1,'Dog','DogBliksem')

Insert into @Param(TID,ParamType,Val) values(2,'Parent','ParentParker')
Insert into @Param(TID,ParamType,Val) values(2,'Parent','ParentScarlett')
Insert into @Param(TID,ParamType,Val) values(2,'Child','ChildBrett')
Insert into @Param(TID,ParamType,Val) values(2,'Child','ChildBritney')
Insert into @Param(TID,ParamType,Val) values(2,'Child','ChildBronwyn')
Insert into @Param(TID,ParamType,Val) values(2,'Dog','DogRover')
Insert into @Param(TID,ParamType,Val) values(2,'Dog','Dog2')
Insert into @Param(TID,ParamType,Val) values(2,'Dog','Dog3')




;with cte  as (
Select TID,Val as 'Parent' 
from @Param p
where  p.ParamType = 'Parent'
 )
Select cte.TID,cte.Parent,p.Val as 'Child' 
from cte  
left outer join @Param p on p.TID = cte.TID and  p.ParamType = 'Child'




--The required results will be (for ticket 1)
--TID       Parent          Child           Dog
--1     ParentPeter     ChildSam        DogDogMatix
--1     ParentPeter     ChildSam        DogSnowy
--1     ParentPeter     ChildSam        DogBliksem
--1     ParentPeter     ChildPete       DogDogMatix
--1     ParentPeter     ChildPete       DogSnowy
--1     ParentPeter     ChildPete       DogBliksem
--1     ParentPeter     ChildJohn       DogDogMatix
--1     ParentPeter     ChildJohn       DogSnowy
--1     ParentPeter     ChildJohn       DogBliksem
--1     ParentPeter     null            null
--1     ParentPeter     ChildSam        null
--1     ParentPeter     ChildPete       null
--1     ParentPeter     ChildJohn       null

--1     ParentSally     ChildSam        DogDogMatix
--1     ParentSally     ChildSam        DogSnowy
--1     ParentSally     ChildSam        DogBliksem
--1     ParentSally     ChildPete       DogDogMatix
--1     ParentSally     ChildPete       DogSnowy
--1     ParentSally     ChildPete       DogBliksem
--1     ParentSally     ChildJohn       DogDogMatix
--1     ParentSally     ChildJohn       DogSnowy
--1     ParentSally     ChildJohn       DogBliksem
--1     ParentSally     null            null
--1     ParentSally     ChildSam        null
--1     ParentSally     ChildPete       null
--1     ParentSally     ChildJohn       null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I think you should consider rethinking your data model a little, and look into some normalization techniques before going ahead with your project.

But, using your model ( only slightly altering it ), you could accomplish what you're after using the following method.
Simply add nulls for the child / dog levels and use a simple cross apply query to create the Cartesian product you seem to be after. There's no need for recursive queries, since your data isn't defined recursively.
But, this will work :

```
declare @Ticket table
(
TID int
)

declare @EntityTypes table
(
 id int primary key,
 name varchar(20)
)

declare @TicketEntities table
(ID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
 TicketId int,
 TypeId INT,
 EntityName varchar(40)
)


Insert into @Ticket(TID) values(1)
Insert into @Ticket(TID) values(2)

insert into @EntityTypes (id, name) values (1, 'Parent');
insert into @EntityTypes (id, name) values (2, 'Child');
insert into @EntityTypes (id, name) values (3, 'Dog');

Insert into @TicketEntities(TicketId,TypeId,EntityName) values(1,1,'Peter')
Insert into @TicketEntities(TicketId,TypeId,EntityName) values(1,1,'Sally')
Insert into @TicketEntities(TicketId,TypeId,EntityName) values(1,2,'Sam')
Insert into @TicketEntities(TicketId,TypeId,EntityName) values(1,2,'Pete')
Insert into @TicketEntities(TicketId,TypeId,EntityName) values(1,2,'John')
Insert into @TicketEntities(TicketId,TypeId,EntityName) values(1,2,NULL)
Insert into @TicketEntities(TicketId,TypeId,EntityName) values(1,3,'Matix')
Insert into @TicketEntities(TicketId,TypeId,EntityName) values(1,3,'Snowy')
Insert into @TicketEntities(TicketId,TypeId,EntityName) values(1,3,'Bliksen')
Insert into @TicketEntities(TicketId,TypeId,EntityName) values(1,3,NULL)

Insert into @TicketEntities(TicketId,TypeId,EntityName) values(2,1,'Parker')
Insert into @TicketEntities(TicketId,TypeId,EntityName) values(2,1,'Scarlett')
Insert into @TicketEntities(TicketId,TypeId,EntityName) values(2,2,'Brett')
Insert into @TicketEntities(TicketId,TypeId,EntityName) values(2,2,'Britney')
Insert into @TicketEntities(TicketId,TypeId,EntityName) values(2,2,'Bronwyn')
Insert into @TicketEntities(TicketId,TypeId,EntityName) values(2,2,NULL)
Insert into @TicketEntities(TicketId,TypeId,EntityName) values(2,3,'Rover')
Insert into @TicketEntities(TicketId,TypeId,EntityName) values(2,3,'Sam')
Insert into @TicketEntities(TicketId,TypeId,EntityName) values(2,3,'Laika')
Insert into @TicketEntities(TicketId,TypeId,EntityName) values(2,3,NULL)

Select par.ticketId, par.EntityName as Parent, child.EntityName as Child, dogs.EntityName as Dog
from @TicketEntities as par
    CROSS JOIN @TicketEntities child
    CROSS JOIN @TicketEntities dogs
where
    par.TypeId in (select id from @EntityTypes where name = 'Parent') AND par.TicketId = 1
    AND child.TypeId in (select id from @EntityTypes where name = 'Child') AND child.TicketId = 1
    AND dogs.TypeId in (select id from @EntityTypes where name = 'Dog') AND dogs.TicketId = 1
```